# get HttpServletRequest in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC. I am not using Spring boot dependencies.

I created the AuthenticationSuccessEventListener class, this class implements the ApplicationListener interface.

How do I get the HttpServletRequest in the AuthenticationSuccessEventListener class? I tried many options, but I still could not find the answer to my question.

When trying to get the HttpServletRequest, I get an exception.

**Message:** `No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Who can, tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

```
    @Component
    public class AuthenticationFailureListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

        // This option doesn't work.
        // @Autowired
        // HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

        // This option doesn't work.
        // HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent a) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: what are you planning to do with HttpServletRequest in this listener?